# Нужно ли пересоздать Provisioning profile при смене Push SSL Certificate?

Tags: ios, apple, mobile, azure

Есть мобильное приложение для ios. Получает push-уведомления через Azure. Push-сертификат (Production Push SSL Certificate) скоро истекает. То есть, его нужно пересоздать. Нужно ли после этого пересоздать Provisioning profile, которым подписывается приложение при сборке?